# Secure the sandbox of an application on iOS to avoid copying its content

Tags: ios, security, encryption, sandbox

I am developing an application in which files are downloaded from a server and stored for consumption within the application.

As a Business mandate, the highest possible security must be maintained, in such a way as to prevent those files from being extracted from the application and then distributed in other ways.

I know that for a while, Apple has made it difficult to access the documents inside the Sandox, but is it totally secure? Could it be extracted? What can be done to avoid copying those files?

Thank you